# NVCC compiler can't find random library

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to use random library,which contains uniform_real_distribution function to generate uniform random number. When I use g++ then the code  works perfectly but when I try to use this library(random) in cuda code (in the host part) and I try to use nvcc the compiler nvcc the it can't find random library. Is there any to make nvcc see the library or is there any way around?

Comment: Did you install this library in that environment?

Comment: Can you post the full commands you use for compiling in both cases, along with the error message in the failing case?

Comment: please also identify which version of gnu compiler tools and libraries you are using, as well as CUDA version

Comment: What do you mean that nvcc does not see the library? Do you have compilation errors or linkage errors? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that Nividia compiler (nvcc) still can't understand some library that have been added recently in C++11 libraries. One of those library is random library which nvcc can't understand it.In other words we have to wait until Nividia make nvcc understand what is going on in some of the C++11 libraries.